# Authenticate Xamarin app with ADAL against Azure AD

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, adal

I have an Xamarin.Forms portable project, now only for iOS, where we authenticate against Azure AD with the ADAL library. It works very well when the user enters username and password.

But now I need to create a version of the app without username/password. I have created a new app inn Azure AD with a App key and changed the app to identify it selves with this app/key.

When testing the authentication class in a console application I got the Bearer token back. But in the Xamarin project I got a Null pointer exception when calling AcquireTokenAsync.

Any here managed to get this working and can point me in the correct direction?

The different id/keys are replaced with fake ones…

ADAL version 3.13.8.

This is the class doing the authentication, the exception is thrown in the last function:

```
internal class AppAuthenticationHelper
{
    private const string AadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/";

    private const string Tenant = "xxx.yyyyy.com";
    private const string ClientId = "ddsgreg-grg-rgerg-argerg-qrgqreg";
    private const string AppIdUri = "https://xxx.yyyy.com";
    private const string AppKey = "asegfuoyagfoygaefouygauyfaeuyrfg2;

    private static readonly string Authority = $"{AadInstance}{Tenant}";

    private readonly AuthenticationContext authContext;
    private readonly ClientCredential clientCredential;

    public AppAuthenticationHelper()
    {
        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority);
        clientCredential = new ClientCredential(ClientId, AppKey);
    }

    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync()
    {
        return await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(AppIdUri, clientCredential);
    }
}
```

Console test program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var auth = new AppAuthenticationHelper();
        var t = auth.AcquireTokenAsync();
        t.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        if (t.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(t.Result.AccessTokenType);
            Console.WriteLine(t.Result.AccessToken);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

A bit more complicated to show the Xamarin code, but here are some pieces:

```
    private async Task<AuthenticationHeaderValue> CreateAuthHeader()
    {
        var appAuth = new AppAuthenticationHelper();
        var ar = await appAuth.AcquireTokenAsync();
        if (ar != null)
        {
            return new AuthenticationHeaderValue(ar.AccessTokenType, ar.AccessToken);
        }

        throw new Exception();
    }


    protected HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var httpClient = HttpMessageHandler != null ? new HttpClient(HttpMessageHandler) : new HttpClient();

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        return httpClient;
    }

    protected async Task<string> SendAsync(string requestUri, string payload)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri);
        request.Headers.Authorization = AuthHeader;
        request.Content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var httpClient = GetHttpClient())
        {
            var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken);
            httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the detailed exception you have got in the Xamarin for iOS?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT: I get an NullReferenceException exception in AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync.

Comment: Are you able to see the detail exception from Azure AD like `AADSTSxxxx`? Is it helpful to capture the request using **Fiddler**?